# Features in KNN in a plane

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

i'm studying a bit of ML and i got stucked. Suppose i want to do some text classification using k neighbours. I use tfidf vectorizer to create a Matrix term-document where for each Cell is stored the tf-idf value.
Now, how can i plot points on the plane? I mean for x1-y1, y1 is the predicted class of document 1, but x?

Each term in the document X1 is an element of the Vector? I mean i cant really understand in text classification which are the points on the plane and how to visualize them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one cannot plot text data on a plane, the way you would plot a set of (x,y) points.

On a plane, one option is to pick two dimensions of x values, with the document class represented using the color or shape of the point. Here the x values are the tf-idf values that you have computed. Typically the tf-idf matrix tends to be sparse, so this visualization may not be useful.

A technique which is generally used in text processing is to perform dimensionality reduction on the tf-idf matrix, and represent the documents in a reduced space. [LSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) is one method to do this. Each document is then represented as a point in the new space. By picking the first two dimensions as x and y values, the documents can now be visualized better.

This is just one example of a visualization. If you have a better idea of the kind of relationships that you want to identify, then that can be used to guide the choice of visualization method.